# Why do we not need to enter username and password in wlst command prompt?

Tags: java, weblogic, wlst

When I use the wlst to connect the weblogic server port, I enter "connect()", then I directly enter the enter key without username and password, and it can connect.
Why? How do the wlst handle this?
And I red the code of "wlst.cmd", I didn't see anything about this.
Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

See this is simple default values of WebLogic domains. If you are installed standalone server on Windows machine(or *nix) where localhost defined with 127.0.0.1 and the admin port as 7001. If your domain don't have this values then it is not going to connect with the connect() command.

Hope you understand this default parameters can be given to any function in Python(WLST).